# How to create dynamic Profile URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I am working with CakePHP

I want to create multiple user and each user should have his profile url..
Like if i am creating a user " Henrick " then URL should make mysite.com/henrick and other action URL should follow the profile URL like

```
mysite.com/henrick/view/managers

mysite.com/henrick/view/add
```

Just confused and how to do this..
any help or any suggestion please.

Comment: Read the manual http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: @burzum : i have already read this link.. But hope you can give me some help instead of Down vote.. :(

Comment: No, you clearly have not, what you want is explained there, even with example code, ready for copy and paste... http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a route just as @burzum indicated.

I'll make some assumptions about your url structure.

```
<?php
// app/Config/routes.php
Router::connect('/:username/:action/:controller', [], ['username' => '[a-z0-9-_]+', 'pass' => ['username']]);
// Routes to Controller::action($username)
```

Who knows what your other url is, view and add are two different controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

you  can use route.
Define your own routes in the `app/Config/routes.php` file using the `Router::connect()` method
 basic format for a route definition is

```
Router::connect(
 'URL',
 array('default' => 'defaultValue'),
 array('option' => 'matchingRegex')
);
```

[see documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)